# Does Decoder require an external data representation that has keys?

Tags: swift, decoding

**What have I done?**

I read over Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) on the topic.

**Details**

The Swift standard library defines a standardized approach to data encoding and decoding.

I realized that all the examples I have come across decode data from an external data representation that has keys like `JSON`, `PLIST`, and `XML` (custom).

I came across a use case where the external data representation doesn't have keys.
For example, when reading data from bluetooth devices. You receive data formatted in an `Array` of `UInt8`.

When exploring Apple's documentation and custom `Decoder` implementations I realized that all external data representations have keys.

I am wondering if Apple's solution leaves enough wiggle room to work with an external data representation that doesn't use keys i.e an `Array` of `UInt8`.

Comment: There is `UnkeyedDecodingContainer` and `UnkeyedEncodingContainer`. Is that what you are looking for? Also, a `Array<UInt8>` is not an external representation. Do you mean arbitrary binary data? You can encode keys in any way you want if you can output any arbitrary bytes.

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry, yes `Array<UInt8>` is how the `Data` is formatted according to the Bluetooth standard. The array is then processed to form data models with properties of various types (integers, floats, booleans). 

Sorry, If I am miss understanding something here. I am aware of `UnkeyedDecodingContainer`.

Comment: Well if you know `UnkeyedDecodingContainer`, what is there to ask? It is designed to process arrays of codable things, like "data models with properties of various types (integers, floats, booleans)".

Comment: The fact that it is an `Array<UInt8>` doesn't matter. JSON is also just a `Array<UInt8>`. Actually everything in a computer is just `Array<UInt8>`. I'm not familiar with bluetooth's protocol, but if you say "data models with properties of various types (integers, floats, booleans)", that sounds like the data indeed has keys to identify each property. In any case, if something is not supported, the decoder/encoder can simply throw an error.

Comment: @Sweeper The JSON equivalent would be "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" that is then mapped onto a data model, is this possible?

Comment: @Sweeper That's not correct. We rely on flags created from the first two `UInt8` values in the array. The flags property is of Array<Bool> and it's composed of a single `UInt16` value that is composed from two <UInt8> values. 
These flags are then used to determine what values are available in the data payload. We basically iterate through the remaining array creating each property in the model. Like I said no keys.

Comment: A `Decoder` is always allowed to throw an error if someone requests a [`container(keyedBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decoder/container(keyedby:)) but the underlying data isn't keyed; to that extent, if your format simply cannot support keyed contents, then you'll just always end up throwing an error — which is technically valid. However, most types do expect to use a keyed container to encode and decode, so they won't be usable with your `Decoder`.

Comment: If the only types you ever expect to decode are ones which you control (i.e., they know to only request unkeyed containers), then it may be simpler and easier to avoid going through `Decodable` altogether and write your own decoding primitives, unless you expect these types to also be encoded/decoded into other formats too.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Okay, that's what I suspected thank you for verifying.

Comment: (I've gone ahead and written up an answer based on these comments.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might have misunderstood what the Codable API is for. It is not for writing the logic for parsing and writing the binary data - you still have to write that yourself.

`Codable` allows you to encode and decode in a more *abstract* way, through keyed, unkeyed, and single value containers. You can say things like:

- get a keyed container with these keys
- get a unkeyed container
- encode XXX with YYY key
- decode a value with XXX key as YYY type
- encode XXX as the next value of this unkeyed container
- decode the next value of this unkeyed container as XXX type

You write how you want your models to be encoded/decoded in terms of these operations, then the `Decoder`/`Encoder` will do the corresponding thing to the underlying binary data.

For example, if you want to decode a JSON array with 5 integers, into a struct with 5 `Int` properties, you write:

```
struct MyModel: Decodable {
    let a, b, c, d, e: Int
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        a = try container.decode(Int.self)
        b = try container.decode(Int.self)
        c = try container.decode(Int.self)
        d = try container.decode(Int.self)
        e = try container.decode(Int.self)
    }
}
```

For JSON, `unkeyedContainer()` means "get ready to decode a JSON array", and "decode(Int.self)" means "read the next array element as an `Int`". Note that you don't have to write how exactly to parse the JSON.

`Decoder`/`Encoder` implementations doesn't have to support all of those operations. If the implementation doesn't support some method for any reason, they can throw an error when that method is called.

For a series of bytes, you can implement your own `Decoder` that supports `unkeyedContainer()` only, and `decode(T.self)` would read x number of bytes depending on `T`, and convert that into the correct type, a bit like a [BinaryReader](https://github.com/rinsuki/BinaryReader).

```
// just rough sketch of an implementation, not complete
struct _BinaryDecoder: Decoder, UnkeyedDecodingContainer {
    var isAtEnd: Bool {
        data.count >= currentIndex
    }
    
    var currentIndex: Int = 0
    
    func hasNBytes(_ n: Int) -> Bool {
        data.count - currentIndex >= n
    }
    
    mutating func decode(_ type: Float.Type) throws -> Float {
        guard hasNBytes(4) else { throw someError }
        let f = data.withUnsafeBytes { buffer in
            buffer.loadUnaligned(fromByteOffset: currentIndex, as: Float.self)
        }
        currentIndex += 4
        return f
    }
    
    mutating func decode(_ type: Int32.Type) throws -> Int32 {
        guard hasNBytes(4) else { throw someError }
        let i = data.withUnsafeBytes { buffer in
            buffer.loadUnaligned(fromByteOffset: currentIndex, as: Int32.self)
        }
        currentIndex += 4
        return i
    }
    
    let data: Data
    
    func unkeyedContainer() throws -> UnkeyedDecodingContainer {
        self
    }
}

struct BinaryDecoder {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T {
        try T.init(from: _BinaryDecoder(data: data))
    }
}
```

You can then implement `init(from:)` in your model like this:

```
var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
let flags = try container.decode(UInt16.self)
switch flags {
    // use container.decode to initialise different properties based on flags
    // e.g. if the next bytes represent two 32-bit signed ints, and then a float
    case 0:
        property1 = try container.decode(Int32.self)
        property2 = try container.decode(Int32.self)
        property3 = try container.decode(Float.self)
}
```

Though, if you are only ever going to decode this one type of binary data, it's probably easier to just write your decoding logic without using `Codable`.

Comment: this is a great starting point, I appreciate the example. Marked this as accepted correct answer.

Comment: I didn't realize that some of the logic should probably exist in the init(from:) method  of the given model since every model will have unique and dynamic logic that it needs to follow given the flags and model properties (order and type).

Answer (score 2):

[`Decoder.container(keyedBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decoder/container(keyedby:)) is documented to throw an error (`DecodingError.typeMismatch`) if the `Decoder` does not have keyed data available to decode. To that extent, if a `Decoder` represents a format which simply cannot be made to support keyed data, then it could always throw an error when keyed data is requested.

However, such a `Decoder` wouldn't be terribly useful with arbitrary types, as most types default to encoding and decoding from keyed data; this is the default behavior when using the compiler's synthesized `Encodable`/`Decodable` conformances.

If you'd use a `Decoder` like this to decode only types which you control (and which know to request only unkeyed containers), it would likely be simpler and easier to avoid the `Codable` APIs altogether, and write your own encoding and decoding tooling.

It sounds, based on your description of the format, that this format is unlikely to be a good fit for `Codable`, and vice versa. (Which is okay too! `Codable` is not intended to be a perfect fit for *all* data formats.)

Comment: That answers my question, much appreciated. I am curious to learn what Apple uses to initialize or set each property when decoding. I don't think I have the understanding to create my own decoding primitives yet, even if the data was keyed.

Comment: @3366784 Re: "decoding primitives" — sorry, that was poor phrasing on my part. I've updated the answer to say "decoding tooling", as in, your own parsing code. Sweeper's answer also covers this much better.

Comment: As for learning more about the implementations of how, e.g.,. `JSONDecoder` works: the code is open-source and viewable! Here is [the current implementation of `JSONDecoder`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/9f53cc551e065d73b327a80147895822bc8f89e0/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/JSONEncoder.swift#L1038), as well as the [rewrite](https://github.com/apple/swift-foundation/blob/main/Sources/FoundationEssentials/JSON/JSONDecoder.swift) coming in the updated `swift-foundation` package.

Comment: The gist of the current implementation: `JSONSerialization` is used to parse and decode all of the JSON, then `JSONDecoder` provides "views" over the data, converting it as needed to the types the user requests. In the coming rewrite, decoding of JSON is done lazily as values are requested, but the idea is largely the same.

Comment: I was confused by the default/automatic initialization that comes from the Codable protocol. In the case where the model property names have the same naming as the JSON data. I didn't understand how that was being done automatically but in my case it looks like I would need to implement the model's init(from:) method and not rely on the automatic/default Codable implementation anyways.

Comment: The automatic `Codable` implementation is generated by the compiler (like a macro); it creates a `CodingKeys` enum on your behalf (with one entry per property on your type), and then generates an `init(from:)`/`encode(to:)` by encoding each property with its corresponding `CodingKey`. This gives some flexibility, as you can provide your own `CodingKeys` enum to customize some amount of behavior, without having to write the whole `init(from:)`... But this is all done at compile-time, outside of the responsibility of any `Encoder`/`Decoder`.

Comment: Here's a slightly more detailed overview of how this works: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-does-automatic-codable-compliance-work-for-the-sake-of-extending-it/25933/3