# Custom binary encoder

Tags: swift, serialization

Swift standard library provides two `Encoder` implementations: for JSON and for Property List. Both (not 100 percent sure about PL though) support keyed containers for storing structures. What if the destination format hasn't notion of keyed objects and just stores fields in order? Can `Codable` protocol be used in this scenario? If not, how to implement something similar? Specifically, who is actually responsible for a generation of a serialisation code for structs inheriting `Codable`? In Rust for comparison it would be done by a macro, but I'm very new to Swift

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66821181/how-to-break-down-hex-data-into-usable-data-from-ble-device-speed-and-cadence ? It's hard to tell, but I guess that's what you are looking for, and there is currently nothing done, it's up to you to do it yourself.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77101382/5133585) might help.

Answer (score 0):

When you conform a type to [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) (or its constituent protocols, [`Encodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable) and [`Decodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable)), the compiler will auto-generate implementations of:

1. A nested enum which conforms to [`CodingKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codingkey)
2. [`init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable/init(from:)-8ezpn)
3. [`func encode(to encoder: any Encoder) throws`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable/encode(to:)-7ibwv)

These predate the macro system, and are just baked into the compiler. You can implement any of these yourself, if you want behaviour that differs from the compiler-provided defaults.

(And since they're just regular methods, you *can* generate them with a macro, if you need).

> What if the destination format hasn't notion of keyed objects and just stores fields in order?

You'll need to write the mapping between field names and order. I would suggest you document this carefully.

Developers write their properties in whatever order makes sense for them (alphabetical, most important to least important, new to old, etc.), and would expect that they can reorder them without any behavioural impact.

Perhaps it would be a good idea to have something explicit like:

```swift
protocol OrderedCodable: Codable {
    static var propertySerializationOrder: [CodingKey]
}

struct Point: OrderedCodable {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int

    static var propertySerializationOrder { [.x, .y] }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.encode(self.x)
        try container.encode(self.y)
    }
}
```

This doesn't actually enforce that the encoding serializes in the order of `propertySerializationOrder`, but even just aving it calls some attention to it. A macro could be written to generate this `encode(to:)` method from it, though.